# Streaming vs chunking in WCF REST service

Tags: web-services, wcf, http, rest, streaming

Can anyone explain me the difference between **chunking** and **streaming** and which method should be preferred when uploading big files from iPad to WCF REST service? Right now we have timeout error when uploading big files from iPad and we'd like to fix this. Our key requirement is that WCF Service should know whether the whole file is uploaded or not. So when client by some reason won't be able to upload the whole file WCF should not perform any operation on uploaded content (as far as I understand streaming upload won't allow to implement this).

Some more questions that confuse me:

1) How both of these modes are working in terms of HTTP?

2) I found that in chunked mode there is header "trasnfer-encoding: chunked" in the first request. Then client sends chunks within separate requests to server and a final zero-length request. Do I need to set trasnfer-encoding header in every request? What other headers should be used?

3) Do I need to send only one HTTP request in streaming mode?

4) Do I need to tell WCF Service somehow that I'm sending streamed content?

5) Let's say default connection timeout for WCF service is 30 seconds. How this timeout affect 
streaming and chunking modes?

6) Can anyone explain in short how both of these modes should be implemented on server and client? (No code required, just high level description). The more I read on this topic the more I'm getting confused.

Many thanks!

Comment: I've got a lot of similar questions. We're you ever able to find answers to your questions?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. These questions are still opened for me. In terms of WCF Service streaming means that incoming request is not buffered and is processed when it's received. That's enough for a project I'm working on but I still eager to learn more on this topic.